# What does the _MainThread mean here for thread.run()?

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is a python code snippet.

```
import threading

class myThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.threadID = threadID
                self.name = name
                self.counter = counter

        def run(self):
                currentTreadname = threading.currentThread()
                print "running in", currentTreadname
```

Let's instance class myThread

```
thread = myThread(1,"mythrd",1)
```

And call  run method in it.

```
thread.run()
running in <_MainThread(MainThread, started 139982993762048)>
```

What does the _MainThread mean here for thread.run() ? 
In the manual of threading:

```
The standard run() method invokes the callable object passed to the object’s constructor as the target argument.
```

1.Here are two objects, for my example, the first one callable object means `_MainThread`?
The second object in `to the object’s constructor` means myThread’s constructor ,right or not?
2.Why run method in son class can invoke parent class?

```
thread.run()
running in <_MainThread(MainThread, started 139982993762048)>
```

thread is the instance of son class--myThread(1,"mythrd",1),why thread.run() revoke a _MainThread  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the Thread.start() method.

```
import threading  

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):                                                                                                                                                                            
        currentTreadname = threading.currentThread()
        print "running in", currentTreadname

thread = myThread(1, "mythread", 1)
thread.start()
```

The output is :

```
running in <myThread(mythread, started 140140930873088)>
```

> start()
>
> Start the thread’s activity.
>
> It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.
>
> run()
>
> Method representing the thread’s activity.
>
> You may override this method in a subclass. The standard run() method invokes the callable object passed to the object’s constructor as the target argument, if any, with sequential and keyword arguments taken from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively.

So as the doc said, **start() method start the thread's activity, yes, this activity is run() method.**

*update*

**The standard run() method invokes the callable object passed to the object’s constructor as the target argument.**

The second object is your myThread instance, you are right. But the callable object is not you said.  check this threading.Thread definition:

```
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
```

> target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method. Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.

The callable object is the target parameter you pass it. more about this you can refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

**And why your code print `running in <_MainThread(MainThread, started 139982993762048)>`?**

Because you do not call the `Thread.start` method, so it will not start a new thread. So if you just call the `myThread.run`, It is a just normal object method calling. It is called in mainThread. So it will print this.

Comment: The standard run() method invokes the callable object passed to the object’s constructor as the target argument.Here are two objects in my example, the first one callable object means  `_MainThread`? The second object in  ` to the object’s constructor ` means  `myThread `,right or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow [GuangshengZuo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3013527/guangshengzuo) answer as above if you want to use threads correctly, I tried to provide the answer you were looking for:
_MainThread is a class in threading module. You can easily check the type of the variable **currentTreadname**  as I did is below:

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.threadID = threadID
            self.name = name
            self.counter = counter

    def run(self):
            currentTreadname = threading.currentThread()
            print("running in", type(currentTreadname))
thread = myThread(1,"mythrd",1)
thread.run()
```

Output:

```
running in <class 'threading._MainThread'>
```

Comment: It is arguably a special kind of dummy thread (a thread that is not created by python). Additional dummy threads can be created if threads are created by C libraries that then call back to Python; they will be of type `threading._DummyThread`.